# Change JLabel and wait for sometime to exit

Tags: java, sleep

I want to change the label when I click the button, and then after 3 seconds exit the program. But if I click the button, label does not change. It just exits after 3 seconds. This is my logic

1. Change the label.
2. Sleep for 3 seconds
3. Then exit the program.

   ```
   btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           System.out.println("Stopping the program.");
           state.setText("Bye...");
           state.setBackground(SystemColor.textHighlight);
           doStop();
       }
   });

   state = new JLabel("Not listening");
   state.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
   state.setBackground(new Color(204, 0, 51));
   state.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
   state.setBounds(10, 222, 488, 24);
   state.setOpaque(true);
   frame.getContentPane().add(state);
   ```

   `public void doStop() {
       try{
               Thread.sleep(3000);
               }       catch(InterruptedException e){
              }
           System.exit(0);     }`

Comment: Isnt your button called `btnNewButton_1` ? So use `btnNewButton_1.setText("Bye...");`

Comment: try repaint(); your frame

Comment: Unless `state.setText("Bye...");` internally calls `btnNewButton_1.setText("Bye...");` then this will not change the text of the button.

Comment: Also, calling `doStop()` from the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.htm) will make your GUI completely unresponsive while the thread sleeps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `javax.swing.Timer` like:

```
final Timer time= new Timer(3000,new ActionListener()
{ 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {   
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

remove you `doStop` method, include this your code. Your button's `actionListener` would be like this

```
 System.out.println("Stopping the program.");
 state.setText("Bye...");
 state.setBackground(SystemColor.textHighlight);
 time.start();
```

Doc:

> Fires one or more ActionEvents at specified intervals. An example use
>   is an animation object that uses a Timer as the trigger for drawing
>   its frames.

Learn [MORE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

Comment: Make sure your import is `javax.swing.Timer`

Comment: yep, eclipse was import this `import com.sun.speech.freetts.util.Timer;`. Now after I change it to `javax.swing.Timer` its working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use javax.swing.TImer insted in your doStop(). Like this

```
public void doStop() {
    Timer t=new Timer(3000, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: Its giving me an error, `the constructor timer is undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the problem is the thread.sleep, try to use a timer instead.
There is an exemple :

```
public void doStop() {
long savedTime=System.currentTimeMillis(), actualTime=System.currentTimeMillis();

while((savedTime+3000 > actualTime) ){
    actualTime=System.currentTimeMillis()
}
System.exit(0);}
```

Comment: Its the same as before.